# Создать Excel файл

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Как создать .xls файл без установленного экселя? Обрыл все, ненашел никаких вариантов кроме `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, которому нужен эксель, и который уже даже майкрософт не рекомендует использовать. Что делать, дайте пжл совет.

Comment: Гляньте в сторону [SpreadsheetDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.spreadsheetdocument.aspx)

Comment: [How to create an Excel file in .NET using OpenXML](http://www.dispatchertimer.com/tutorial/how-to-create-an-excel-file-in-net-using-openxml-part-1-basics/)

Comment: Попробуйте EPPlus